# Run failed Rspec which send message from Gmail, which works fine in RubyMine

Tags: rspec, terminal, gmail, rubymine

I have some rspec tests in RubyMine, they works perfect, when I run them from RubyMine interface.
But when I try to run same test from terminal, they fail.
I use ruby-gmail gem to send mail trougth gmail using this construction:

```
@gmail.deliver do
        to current_unread_mail.reply_to
        subject "Re: " + current_unread_mail.title
        body reply_body
end
```

It's successfully send mail if I run from RubyMine, but didn't send mail (but not raising any kind of exception) when I run my rspec like this

```
rspec test_spec.rb
```

So I think the reason for this, that RubyMine add some additional rspec parameters, when it runs.

First line in Rspec output in RubyMine is something like this:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin/rspec /home/user/path_to_spec/test_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter
```

But If I run this code from terminal I got error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$0=ARGV.shift'
```

What can I do?

Comment: How do you run specs from terminal? Have you tried just `rspec spec` or `rake spec` if you have corresponding `rake` tasks available?

Comment: I don't use rake. I run rspec like this `rspec test_spec.rb`

Comment: Could you provide isolated example in which this error occurs?

Comment: Could you show me the PROJECT_ROOT/.rspec file if present?

Comment: There is no such file in PROJECT_ROOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem.
I used a [Ruby-Gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail) gem, but when I switched for [Gmail](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) gem (fork of [Ruby-Gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail)) and changes syntax to

```
email = @gmail.compose do
 to (current_unread_mail.reply_to.mailbox + '@' + current_unread_mail.reply_to.host).to_s
 subject "Re: " + current_unread_mail.title
 body reply_body
end
email.deliver!
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be running the same line as RubyMine to run your specs on the command line. 
All that RubyMine does is include it's own formatter so it can give you the results in a GUI,
so if you got this working there is far more value in just using `rspec spec/...`

Rspec should be used with just the rspec command, your tests will run correctly.

Comment: Yeh, I thought that that RubyMine stuff is just formatters, but still I can't get my rspec working correctly even from `rspec spec.rb` command, maybe some problem in gem bundle

Comment: Could you add the output when you run `rspec spec`? Bundle issues are common, make sure your bundle is good using `bundle check` and perhaps run rspec with `bundle exec rspec spec`.